# How to fix Kong timers always running and not response?

Tags: api-gateway, kong, konga

When I access to my Kong metric the kong_nginx_timers{state="running"} = 33, why it always 33 ? and sometime it's increase more than 100+ running and not response anything when my user request. please help !

```
kong_nginx_timers{state="running"} 33
```

[Metric image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiDOD.png)

[Metric image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr3dk.png)

Is there an existing issue for this?